# Can't Seem To Display Drop Down Value

Tags: javascript, html

The codes below indicate that the drop down value selected from the both drop down list will be redirected or referred to the another HTML page. I've got the first one done but I couldn't redirect the value from the 'Status' drop down menu. Need help on this one. Preferred language : Javascript & HTML.

This is the 'mainTest.html' page where the drop down list will be displayed/selected.

```js
  window.onload = passParameters;

//Function to update "showdata" div with URL Querystring parameter values
function passParameters() {
  var foodbeverage = getParameterByName("foodbeverage");
  var status = getParameterByName("status");
  if (foodbeverage != null && status != null) {
    var data = "<b>Food Beverages:</b> " + foodbeverage + " <b>Dine/Takeaway:</b> " + status;
    document.getElementById("showdata").innerHTML = data;
  }
}
//Get URL parameter value
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  if (!url) url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


  <div id="showdata" align="center"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the 'newPageTest.html' page where the drop down lists' value selected will be displayed.

```js
  (function() {
    /**
     * Handles the click of the submit button.
     */
    function onSubmitClicked(event) {
      // Get the input element from the DOM.
      var beverage = document.getElementById('foodbeverage'),
        // Get the value from the element.
        beverageValue = beverage.value,
        // Construct the URL.
        url = 'newPageTest.html?foodbeverage=' + encodeURIComponent(beverageValue) + '&status=' + encodeURIComponent(status);

      // Instead of going to the URL, log it to the console.
      location.href = url;
    }

    // Get the button from the DOM.
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('btngo');
    // Add an event listener for the click event.
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', onSubmitClicked);
  })();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div align="center">

    <center>
      <h4 style="color:darkblue">Choose Your Food/Beverage & Quantity : </h3>
    </center>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>

          <font size=2>
            <B>Choose a Food/Beverage : </B>
          </font>

          <select ID="foodbeverage"> 
 
 <optgroup label="DEFAULT">
 <option value = "NONE">NONE</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 <optgroup label="Food">
 <option value = "Chicken Chop">Chicken Chop</option>
 <option value = "Pasta">Pasta</option>
 <option value = "Pizza">Pizza</option>
 <option value = "Chocolate Cake">Chocolate Cake</option>
 <option value = "Red Velvet Cake">Red Velvet Cake</option>
 <option value = "Ice Cream Cake">Ice Cream Cake</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 <optgroup label="Beverages">
 <option value = "Milk">Milk</option>
 <option value = "Fresh Juice">Fresh Juice</option>
 <option value = "Ice Cream">Ice Cream</option>
 <option value = "Coffee">Coffee</option>
 <option value = "Carbonated Can Drink">Carbonated Can Drink</option>
 <option value = "Water">Water</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 </select>
          <br/>

          <font size=2>
            <B>Choose a Food/Beverage : </B>
          </font>

          <select ID="foodbeverage"> 
 
 <optgroup label="DEFAULT">
 <option value = "NONE">NONE</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 <optgroup label="Food">
 <option value = "Chicken Chop">Chicken Chop</option>
 <option value = "Pasta">Pasta</option>
 <option value = "Pizza">Pizza</option>
 <option value = "Chocolate Cake">Chocolate Cake</option>
 <option value = "Red Velvet Cake">Red Velvet Cake</option>
 <option value = "Ice Cream Cake">Ice Cream Cake</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 <optgroup label="Beverages">
 <option value = "Milk">Milk</option>
 <option value = "Fresh Juice">Fresh Juice</option>
 <option value = "Ice Cream">Ice Cream</option>
 <option value = "Coffee">Coffee</option>
 <option value = "Carbonated Can Drink">Carbonated Can Drink</option>
 <option value = "Water">Water</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 </select>
          <br/>

        </td>

        <td>
          <font size=2>
            <B>Dine In or Take Away : </B>
          </font>
          <select ID="status"> 
 
 <optgroup label="DEFAULT">
 <option value = "NONE">NONE</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 <optgroup label="Status">
 <option value = "Dine In">Dine In</option>
 <option value = "Take Away">Take Away</option>
 </optgroup>
 </select>
          <br/>


          <font size=2>
            <B>Dine In or Take Away : </B>
          </font>
          <select ID="status1"> 
 
 <optgroup label="DEFAULT">
 <option value = "NONE">NONE</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 <optgroup label="Status">
 <option value = "Dine In">Dine In</option>
 <option value = "Take Away">Take Away</option>
 </optgroup>
 </select>
          <br/>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


    <br/>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" id="btngo" value="Go" />

    <br/>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `<font>` and `<center>` are obsolete elements. Don't use them. The `align` attribute is also obsolete. Your `<h4>` tags don't match. There should not be a closing slash on `<br>` or `<input>`. The type= in your script tag is not needed.

Comment: @Rob; Thank you for the corrections (I've corrected) but is there any solution for my problem stated as well?

Comment: @cerberus99 so in short from your code what I can see is that you are redirecting on each selection. Am I correct?/

Comment: @Gardezi; Yes, correct. I managed to do for the first one but failed for the second one.

Comment: @cerberus99 you are not able to redirect

Comment: @Gardezi Yes correct

Comment: @cerberus99 what is status ?? and where are you getting it ?

Comment: @Gardezi; 'status' is the dropdown ID where I am unable to redirect. It contains the option of 'Dine In' or 'Take Away'.

Comment: @cerberus99 the problem is where are you getting it and setting the status variable

Comment: @cerberus99 can you please show what is the url after everything is appended

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152975/discussion-between-gardezi-and-cerberus99).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this and this will works

```
var beverage = document.getElementById('foodbeverage'), status = document.getElementById('status') 

beverageValue = beverage.value, status = status.value,
```

the thing is that the sstatus variable is not intialized